# Characterizing a 3-manifold from branched covering over $S^3$ and viceversa

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, covering-spaces

There is a theorem by Alexander that says that any closed oriented 3-manifold can be constructed as a branched covering of $S^3$ over a knot.

But given a 3-manifold how do I find a branched covering over a knot in $S^3$ which gives that manifold?

And viceversa, given the branched covering over a knot how do I find which 3-manifold is it covering? I have read many papers in literature (especially by Fox) and it seems that I can characterize the covered manifold with its fundamental group, is this correct? Is the fundamental group enough to fully characterize the 3-manifold?

Is an answer to the first question that given a 3-manifold its fundamental group I can construct the corresponding knot?

Comment: Among the papers in the literature that you read, I presume one of them has a proof of Alexander's Theorem, which answers your first question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is contained in [1](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-80/issue-6/Every-closed-orientable-3-manifold-is-a-3-fold-branched/bams/1183536038.full) by Hilden: the author proves that every orientable 3-manifold is an (irregular) cover of $S^3$ branched over a knot $K\subset S^3$. Furthermore, the author constructs the knot $K$ from the Heegaard splitting of $M=X_{g}\cup_{\Sigma_{g}} X'_{g}$ and the (irregular) degree 3 cover $\phi: X_{g} \to B^3 $ whose branched in made by $g+2$ arcs.
Here $X_{g}$ denotes the genus $g$ handlebody and $\Sigma_g$ is the genus-$g$ surface.